Connecton between 2 Hadoop clusters
I have 2 Hadoop clusters. I want to connect to cluster 2 in cluster 1 through pyspark. I've tried the connection using spark session in which I specified hive metastore uris and all but still when I'm executing spark.sql() to show a table from cluster 2 it is showing database cannot be found. It is still in cluster 1.
I have also tried jdbc but I don't think the required driver file is present. So anyone could please share any other possible ways.
